# Send attachment from teams personal chat to teams group channel using bot framework

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, botframework

Is it possible to send attachments from the team personal chat to the team group channel.

My requirement is for sending attachments (images/ screenshots/smiley) from team's channel to the personal chat and vice versa . (not directly attaching a png/jpeg file. Need to send the same attachment from the sender to the recipient )

I have tried to pass the same attachment in activity from the sender to the recipient teams, but  it is throwing an exception as 'Bad Request'

```
ConnectorClient connectorClient = new ConnectorClient(new Uri(serviceUrl), microsoftAppCredentials);
connectorClient.Conversations.SendToConversationAsync(MessageActivity);
```

I have tried to send smileys from personal chat to teams channel. I could get Activity.Attachments with ContentType="image/*" and text/html also and the below code is worked and we could send the smiley messsage in teams client.

```
foreach (var attachment in activity.Attachments)
{
if (attachment.ContentType == "text/html")
{
message = attachment.Content.ToString();
}
}
```

But this is not working in case of copy pasting screenshot and while attaching the image using the 'attach' option in teams.

Below is the attachment data what we are getting for image content type.

[image]

We have set supportedFiles to true in the manifest file and used the connector client to send the message in team client but this is also didnt worked to send images